# How to change "No data - -3.40282e+38" in a raster through interpolation using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, interpolation, nodata

I'm working with QGIS 3.16.4-Hannover, elaborating a DEM 2x2m to produce a soil thickness map of an area of 50km2. After some elaboration (curvature, hydrology analysis, ...) now I have a raster with a lot of “no data” and in the window “Property/Information” under “No-data” I read “-3.40282e+38”.
I would to eliminate the no-data cells, introducing interpolated values from the nearest cells. A prerequisite is that the interpolation must have to change value only in the no-data cells.
Anyone can suggest something?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have a GRASS integration in your QGIS (more info [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/grass_integration/grass_integration.html#the-grass-toolbox)), you can use the GRASS algorithm `r.fillnulls` in the Processing Toolbox which "fills no-data areas in raster maps using spline interpolation" (see documentation [here](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.fillnulls.html)).

Comment: Thank you so much. I'd completely removed this function. Thank you

Comment: Great! If this worked for you, kindly select it as an official answer so everyone knows it is solved.